# DIY Corner bathroom sink vanity installation

Tags: plumbing, sink, vanity

I have  this corner sink that I would like to install.

[image: corner sink]

Holes location on sink :

[image: holes on sink]

I have moderate DIY skill and have previously installed a bidet that needed water hose T joint. So I think I can pull this one off.

There is existing water pipe for toilet and floor drain outlet-

T joint location for water connection:

[image: water connection]

Drain /grate connection:

[image: drain]

The house plumbing type is pressurized , there is a main water valve that can be used to shut off water from the mains.

I could think of following parts :

1. Flexible water hose 
   [image: hose]
2. Flexible drain pipe

[image: drain pipe]

3. Strainer Basket

[image]

4. 2x Double headed coach screw ?

Saw them here at 4:00

youtube.com/watch?v=SrUdoKQukZw

Like this -

[image: double thread screw]

5. Any sealant ?
6. Water pipe T-joint

Any thing else I am missing? Any other tips to get this DIY job done would be great.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. Did the sink not come with installation instructions?

Answer (score 1):

Things to consider:

- Most "new location" sink installations require opening of the wall to relocate drain and water-supply plumbing, you do not mention this but need to prepare for it.
- flexible drain tubes are more prone to accumulation of material (clogging) so you may want to consider adjustable tubular slip-joint drain pipes. You do not mention a trap, these are necessary for safety and code compliance.
- The upper flange of the drain assembly (where the drain assembly meets the sink hole) is most often sealed with plumber's putty, you may need some.
- The ability to fasten the sink to the wall with those "coach screws" is totally dependent on wall construction. You may need special anchors or other reinforcement to ensure the attachment is strong enough.

Terminology and methodology is particular by geographic area, so if this does not make sense then we hail from different parts of the world.

Comment: Thanks for your input. The walls are made of brick. The water line will be connected to toilet flush ( pic 3 from top) with a flexible pipe ( pic 5 ) using a T joint. ". You do not mention a trap, these are necessary for safety and code compliance." Would be great if you could post a link to 'trap' to get more details. Thanks

Comment: @MsTechie - For "trap" google "bottle trap", "p-trap", "s-trap", "s-bend" or "u-bend" - they're all variants on traps. (Well, s-trap and s-bend are the same thing with a different name, and a u-bend is essentially the same thing too.